# New instance forgot password

Tags: acumatica

I have a new instance I created a month ago for testing and now I cannot remember the password I used.  I would like to save the data. Is there any way to either reset the admin pw back to setup or can I create a new instance and transfer the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put a temporary password for user 'admin' in the Users table

Answer (score 1):

You can Check password in Table Users like what Gabriel said or reset password by SQL Script below.

> UPDATE Users SET Password = 'setup', LockedOutDate = null WHERE Username = 'admin'